# How do I Set the navigation bar text in the header?

Tags: html, css

I need the Navigation Bar code to be on the header. The text floats underneath the header and I cant figure out for the life of me on how to fix it. What can I do in terms of CSS to be able to contain the text to the header?

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
  <h1>Empowering The Nation </h1>
</div>
<ul class="navigation">
  <a href="Home.html"><b>Home</b></li></a>
  <a href="Courses.html"><b>Courses</li></b></a>
  <a href="Pricing.html"><b>Pricing</b></li></a>
  <a href="Contact.html"><b>Contact Us</b></li></a>
  <a href="Sign In.html"><button>Sign In</li></button></a>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to check your nesting. I can't see any `<li>` tags to match your `</li>` tags.

Comment: Why don't you just place the navigation into the header div? And make your html [valid](https://validator.w3.org/). You have for example 4 closing tags for divs but only 1 opening.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your HTML valid. For example you have useless closing tags `</div>`, there are not `<li>` tags but there are `</li>` tags, etc...
To have the navigation bar in the header,you can just put your code in the header div.
I made some corrections and you can see an example of what it looks like with a valid html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <header>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home.css" />
    <div class="header">
      <div class="page-title">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
        <h1>Empowering The Nation</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="navigation">
          <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Courses.html">Courses</a></li>
          <li><a href="Pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          <!--Why this button ?-->
          <li><a href="Sign In.html"><button>Sign In</button></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <body>
    <div>This is the body of the page</div>
  </body>
</html>

<style>
  .header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .page-title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-self: center;
  }

  img {
    align-self: center;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html is little bit invalid. I fix it. To your problem. You can use flex box. I suggest that you want your list also horizontal. Then i apply display: inline to the the list (ul, li).

**example**

```css
.nav {
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap:20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  
}
.navigation ul, li{
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navigation a {
  color: black ;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
    <h1>Empowering The Nation </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Courses.html">Courses</a></li>
      <li><a href="Pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="Sign In.html">Sign In</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```